# OleDb.ExecuteNonQuery always returning 0

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net, ms-access-2010, oledb

I looked into previously asked such questions but none of the solutions worked for me.

I am having trouble updating a `Boolean` column in my Access database. But the query works just fine in Access.

What I have already tried:

1. Directly using `TRUE` or `FALSE` in the `SqlCommand`
2. Using `Parameters.Add()` instead of `Parameters.AddWithValue()`

My `ClickEvent`:

```vb
Private Sub Update_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btn_update.Click
    Dim mc As New UsersModule() With {
        .UserID = tbx_userid.Text,
        .UserName = tbx_username.Text,
        .UserPassword = tbx_password.Text,
        .UserRole = combx_role.SelectedValue.ToString,
        .UserFullname = tbx_fullname.Text,
        .UserActive = cbx_active.IsChecked
    }

    Dim bridge As New UsersBridge()

    If bridge.UpdateUser(mc) Then
        MsgBox("User's Data Updated Successfully")
    Else
        MsgBox("Something went wrong :/")
    End If

End Sub
```

My Module class:

```vb
Public Class UsersModule

    Private ID As Integer, Name As String, Pass As String, Role As String, Fullname As String, isActive As Boolean

    Public Property UserID() As Integer
        Get
            Return ID
        End Get
        Protected Friend Set(value As Integer)
            ID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property UserName() As String
        Get
            Return Name
        End Get
        Protected Friend Set(value As String)
            Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property UserPassword() As String
        Get
            Return Pass
        End Get
        Protected Friend Set(value As String)
            Pass = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property UserRole() As String
        Get
            Return Role
        End Get
        Protected Friend Set(value As String)
            Role = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property UserFullname() As String
        Get
            Return Fullname
        End Get
        Protected Friend Set(value As String)
            Fullname = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property UserActive() As Boolean
        Get
            Return isActive
        End Get
        Protected Friend Set(value As Boolean)
            isActive = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

My Bridge class:

```vb
Public Class Accounts_Bridge

    Shared conStr As String = Windows.Application.Current.FindResource("connectionString")

    Public Function Update(mc As AccountsData) As Boolean

        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(conStr)
        Dim isSuccessful As Boolean = False

        Try

            Dim sql As String = "UPDATE Users SET UserName = @user, UserPassword = @pass, UserRole = @role, UserFullname = @name, UserActive = @active WHERE UserID = @id"
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = mc.UserID
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mc.UserName
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mc.UserPassword
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@role", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mc.UserRole
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mc.UserFullname
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@active", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = mc.UserActive

            con.Open()
            Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()   'Always Returns 0
            If i > 0 Then
                isSuccessful = True
            Else
                isSuccessful = False
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
        Return isSuccessful

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your Bridge Class? Does the mc variables have values?

Comment: Yes I did debug my Bridge Class, and I do am receiving values in mc variable. @ErrBon

Comment: Incidentally, you can shorten that `If i > 0 Then... End If` to `isSuccessful = i > 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Issue 1**: `user` is a reserved word

`user` is a [reserved word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reserved-words) in Access/OleDB.

Hence you need to escape the term as `[user]` so that the query treats it as the column name.

**Issue 2**: Parameters position

Unlike SQL Server, Access/OleDB doesn't use named parameters; they are just positional placeholders.

Thus, you must supply the parameter values in the [exact order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8) listed in the SQL query.

**Recommendation(s)**

**1.0** You should [stop using `AddWithValue()`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) which this topic had been highly discussed and recommended in Stack Overflow Community.

**1.1** Instead, you need to pass `OleDbType` for each parameter and be sure that the data type and length parsed must match the table column's type.

**2.0** Must declare both `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` with [`Using` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) (these objects are disposable). It's very important that the Connection is disposed.

**2.1** The connection will be disposed automatically once the process is ended for success and failure scenario. Hence, you no need to `con.Close()` manually in the `finally` block.

For fixing the above issues, your code should be as below:

```
Public Function Update(mc As AccountsData) As Boolean

    Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(conStr)
        Dim isSuccessful As Boolean = False

        Try

            Dim sql As String = "UPDATE Users SET UserName = @user, UserPassword = @pass, UserRole = @role, UserFullname = @name, UserActive = @active WHERE UserID = @id"

            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mc.UserName
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mc.UserPassword
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@role", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mc.UserRole
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mc.UserFullname
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@active", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = mc.UserActive
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = mc.UserID

                con.Open()
                Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                If i > 0 Then
                    isSuccessful = True
                Else
                    isSuccessful = False
                End If

            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Return isSuccessful

    End Using

End Function
```

Comment: 1) I know that user is a reserved word in access and therfore i use 'UserName', I actually copied the wrong bridge class, rlly sorry for that.

2) As I have already written in my post, I did try Add() instead of AddWithValue(). But i still get zero rows edited.

Comment: Hi @Cyborg, did you arrange the order of the parameters? As mentioned above for Issue 2, `@id` should be in the last order.

Comment: Thanks @YongShun . It was to do with the order. I never realized that the order was important while passing parameters. Thanks for helping